# Heterogeneous. Is there a verb for this word?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

I am writing a scientific article in which the word *heterogeneous* is used frequently to indicate to the ([CPU + GPU computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogeneous_computing)). However, several occasions I need to express the idea using verb like: *make computing heterogeneous*. I could not find anything other than the *adjective* and *name* (**heterogeneous** & **heterogeneity** respectively). Is there a verb for this name? If not, what good replacement can I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Heterogenize*

[TFD Encycl.](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Heterogenization)

> **heterogenization**: in metallurgy, generation in some metal alloys of a structure consisting of two or more phases of different crystal lattices.

[wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heterogenization)

> **heterogenization**: The process of making or becoming *heterogenic* or *heterogenized*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_homogenization)

> The process of adoption of elements of global culture to local cultures is known as glocalization[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_homogenization)[5] or *cultural heterogenization*.[14]

ant: *homogenize*

Usage:
Ian Jarvie, *[Thinking about Society](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=bRRTSMf5cO4C&pg=PA378&dq=%22heterogenize%22%20-catalyst&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Nm8RU4vKA8i1iQf63YDQDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22heterogenize%22%20-catalyst&f=false)*

> In the struggle to control the market, worsting the competition is part of the battle. As firms grow, they begin to differentiate product, and **heterogenize** content. [emphasis added]

Comment: [A 19th century example](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xiQPAAAAIAAJ&q=%22heterogenize%22&dq=%22heterogenize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1bkRU6ybIomv7AaguYDACw&redir_esc=y)